# SEGUID from python to c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this in C++, I have some code in Python but I can't figure how to make it work in C++

```python
def seguid(seq):

    try:
        #Python 2.5 sha1 is in hashlib
        import hashlib
        m = hashlib.sha1()
    except:
        #For older versions 
        import sha
        m = sha.new()
    import base64
    try:
        #Assume its a Seq object
        seq = seq.tostring()
    except AttributeError:
        #Assume its a string
        pass
    m.update(_as_bytes(seq.upper()))

    try:
        #For Python 2.5+
        return base64.b64encode(m.digest()).rstrip("=")
    except:
        #For older versions
        import os
        #Note: Using os.linesep doesn't work on Windows,
        #where os.linesep= "\r\n" but the encoded string
        #contains "\n" but not "\r\n"
        return base64.encodestring(m.digest()).replace("\n","").rstrip("=")
```

Comment: Let's see your C++ code and we'll help you make it work (we won't write it for you).

Comment: i did only base64_encode & base64_decode

Answer (score 0):

i Think you may embed the python code into C/C++ code.Please refer the following link for more details.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497